# Perforce - how to discard changes for an entire folder?

Tags: versioning, perforce

I have modified and edited some project files in a folder targeted at a windows 32 build and made the project build for a different target. I then copied that folder and renamed it, but I would like the files in the depo to not suffer any modifications for the windows 32 folder.

How can I discard the changes made to the windows 32 folder and substitute the files with the working, depo version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the command line, the following should work:

```
c:\my\root\source\dir> p4 revert windows32/...
c:\my\root\source\dir> p4 sync windows32/...#none
c:\my\root\source\dir> rd /s/q windows32
c:\my\root\source\dir> p4 sync windows32/...
```

I usually remove the directory (hence the `rd`) to catch any files that were mistaken added to the source directory but not the repo.  The `revert` is not necessary unless there are files in *edit* mode in the windows subdirectory.  I usually revert everything just to be safe.  If you get an errors on the `sync windows32/...#none` line, then try replacing `#none` with `#0` instead.